# Word alternative editor that saves in a clean structured format for html import?

Tags: import, ms-word, editor

It's difficult to explain. I have a website and I have clients that are going to provide me with the content of the website. They will usually write down everything in microsoft word which makes it very hard to import.

Is there an alternative to microsoft word that can export to a structured format like xhtml, xml or json?

An editor that allows the user to create sections in which he/she can write his content. ex.  i want the resulting output to be something structured like that

```
<section>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>My content blah blah</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>My content blah blah</p>
  <section>
     <h1>Heading 1</h1>
     <p>My content blah blah</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

That sort of output is easy for me to work with and import in any website. In my example, i can create a new page for each section, a subpage if there is a section in a section, etc..

(When converting a microsoft word to html, there are lots of garbage tags, inline css, etc.., no clean and it's not structured enough)

Comment: I  would suggest you to convert the word to markdown, than to html.

Comment: is markdown easy to work with and import programatically? any recommandation for a good markdown editor?

Comment: Maybe [Pen](https://sofish.github.io/pen/)

Comment: an offline editor would be preferable.

Comment: You can send them the zip and tell them to open Chrome.